# Git branches to be merged in shell script variable

Tags: git, bash, shell, git-merge

I'm creating a an script that merge the branches defined in a shell script variable. Here is part of the script

```
# Here is how we are setting the variable 'branches'
ALL_BRANCHES=`git ls-remote . | cut -d $'\t' -f 2` # THIS WILL INCLUDE THE FOLDER AS PREFIX
includePattern=
if [[ -n "$INCLUDE_PATTERN" ]] ; then
  export IFS=","
  for pattern in $INCLUDE_PATTERN; do
    includePattern="$includePattern -e $REMOTE_FOLDER$pattern"  
  done
fi
branches=`echo "$ALL_BRANCHES" | eval "grep $includePattern"`

echo "B = $branches"
echo "C = git merge -q --no-edit $branches"
git merge -q --no-edit $branches
```

This is the output

```
B = refs/remotes/origin/XXX refs/remotes/origin/XXY
C = git merge -q --no-edit refs/remotes/origin/XXX refs/remotes/origin/XXY
merge: refs/remotes/origin/XXX refs/remotes/origin/XXY - not something we can merge
```

Why this is not working?

**INFO:** When I do a copy&paste of the command (printed by the `echo "C = ..."` it works as expected

**MORE INFO:** When I run `eval "git merge -q --no-edit $branches"` I got another error

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-octopus: 1: eval: Bad substitution
Merge with strategy octopus failed.
```

Comment: How are you setting `branches`?

Comment: What is the actual value of `refs/remotes/origin/XXX`? If it contains quotes or other shell special characters it will not work.

Comment: Shell variable assignments cannot have spaces around the `=` sign. To assign the output of a shell command to a variable you need to use `var=$(command)`.

Comment: @chepner Check the updated question. I added how we are setting the variable

Comment: @thatotherguy actually the `refs/remotes/origin/XXX` is one of the space separeted literal string that I kept in the `$branches`. Its represent valid branch names in git (no special characters in our case)

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not using variable assignation. Maybe you got it wrong seeing the script output instead of the script code.

Comment: That raises the question, how do you set `ALL_BRANCHES` and `includePattern`. The `eval` is either completely unnecessary or an indication that you are going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Based on your last edit, I'm not convinced that one or both of `XXX` and `XXY` actually exist.

Comment: @chepner I updated the question with all the chain of variables that are related to the `$branches` var

Comment: @chepner they exist (They are branches that I've created to work on the script). And also my approach work because when I do a copy&paste of the output It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `export IFS=,`, this line

```
git merge -q --no-edit $branches
```

no longer passes two separate branch references to `git merge`, because whitespace is no longer used for word-splitting. It's as if you typed

```
git merge -q --no-edit "refs/remotes/origin/XXX refs/remotes/origin/XXY"
```

I think the quickest way to fix this is to restore the original value of `IFS` after you are done setting `INCLUDE_PATTERN`:

```
if [[ -n "$INCLUDE_PATTERN" ]] ; then
  old_ifs=$IFS
  export IFS=","
  for pattern in $INCLUDE_PATTERN; do
    includePattern="$includePattern -e $REMOTE_FOLDER$pattern"  
  done
  IFS=$old_ifs
fi
```

This might work better:

```
# Using a here-doc instead of a here string
# to avoid a bug present prior to bash 4.3
IFS=, read -a patterns <<EOF
$INCLUDE_PATTERN
EOF
for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do
  includePattern+=" -e $REMOTE_FOLDER$pattern"
done
```

Comment: Better would be to use a `while IFS= read -r pattern` loop for this to keep the modification to `IFS` scoped as tightly as possible.

Comment: Agreed; this is just the bare minimum that would fix the immediate problem. I didn't feel like rewriting the entire block to do it the right way.